# how to push component state changes to multiple different pages using icefaces

Tags: icefaces

In my project i want to upload a image in one page(ie:in one view),after uploading the image event is generated and bean1 is executed.please provide a solution for updating the loaded image to another page(ie second view)in which i use GraphicImage component.how to refer second view components in  bean1 without generating event from second view.

Is it possible to do ajax push using icefaces 1.8.2 as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

IceFaces uploads a file to a specific path, given by

```
{Application Root}/{Upload directory}/{Session ID}
```

The Upload Directory is specified in web.xml. The Session ID folder is optional, depending on whether you specified the "uniqueFolder" attribute in the  tag. You can also set the upload path as an attribute in the  tag.

You can store the file path in a String or in a session variable through actionListener for the inputFile.

To refer to this path String from Bean2 without using the backing bean, you can bind your components to "#{Bean1.pathString}". If you want to use the backing-bean, you can do:

```
((Bean1) geBean("Bean1")).getPathString()
```

but only if you extend from `AbstractPageBean`. Also, Bean1 should be session scoped for either case.

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks to your reply.My problem was Administrator uploads an image.then how to push image to multiple browsers(multiple users).